# How to stretch table within a cell (nested table) in html?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Nested table does not 100% height of parent td

I have used height="100%" but did not help

**HTML:**

```
<table width="50%" border="1" align="center">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <table border="1" align="center" width="100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align='center'>
                                    <p>Text</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <table border="1" align="center" width="100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align='center'>
                                    <p>Text</p>
                                    <p>Text</p>
                                    <p>Text</p>
                                    <p>Text</p>
                                    <p>Text</p>
                                    <p>Text</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>  
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Actual result: https://jsfiddle.net/fela93/8ysfawve/17/

Comment: why would you use a table to wrap a table ? is it for a mailing or the fun ?

Comment: yeap, for mailing

Comment: Would td relative/ table absolute + coordonates be fine? It will be off the flow and won't stretch the table parent ...